# Django, get the all posts from the Theme

Tags: python, django

Sorry for english.

I have a Themes and there are posts in this themes. I need to get the posts from the current Theme

I tried to get a theme via slug then check the theme id and display all posts under that id, but i dont know how

```py
class Themes(MultipleModelView):
    template_name = 'site/themes.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MultipleModelView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['modeltwo'] = Theme.objects.all()
        context['modelone'] = Subject.objects.all()
        context['modelthree'] = Theme.objects.filter(slug=self.kwargs.get('slug'))
        context['modelfour'] = Post.objects.filter(where_we_are_id = 1)

        return context
```

Model Theme

```py
class Theme(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name="Название")
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='subject')
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True,verbose_name='ссылка на страницу')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']
        verbose_name_plural = 'Темы'
        verbose_name = 'Тема'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

Model Post

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name="Название")
    text = models.TextField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Текст")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Дата создания')
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    where_we_are = models.ForeignKey(Theme,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='get_news',null=True,blank=True )


    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_at']
        verbose_name_plural = 'Посты'
        verbose_name = 'Пост'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Urls

```py
from django.urls import path
from .views import MultipleModelView,Themes
urlpatterns = [
    # path('abc',base.as_view(),name='themes'),
    path('', MultipleModelView.as_view(), name='themes'),
    path('<slug:slug>', Themes.as_view(), name='article_detail'),
]
```

Comment: Please share your `Post` and `Theme` models. together with the relevant `url` paths.

Comment: Sorry, i changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
context['modelfour'] = Post.objects.filter(where_we_are__slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
```

or since you already retrieved the theme, we can work with:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

# …

context['theme'] = theme = get_object_or_404(Theme, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
context['modelfour'] = Post.objects.filter(where_we_are_id=theme)
```

Here we  use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) since normally slugs are unique, an there is thus at most one `Theme` object with the given slug.